# Run JAR file on server

Tags: java, php, apache, server, exec

I wrote a Java program, which creates a text file in the same directory as the .jar file. Now I want to use php to run the .jar.
I tried:

```
exec('java -jar awesomejavaprogram.jar');
```

But I doesn't create the file... I don't get any error message or stacktrace either.

Comment: You should read the manual on how to use [`exec`](http://php.net/function.exec) to better understand how to deal with errors resulting from its use. "*If the `return_var` argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.*".

Answer (score 1):

Java is probably not in php's path.

If you run `which java` from the command line, it should give you the full path, put this into the `exec` and it should work.

Also, if you're running that from a web page, that's not a good idea.